# How to scrape specific vslot template elements with beautiful soup

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape elements from a website which have the tag:

```
    <template v-slot:default-version>
```

I have tried the code below but I cant get it to work. It just returns empty.

```
    soup.find_all(re.compile('<([^ >]+)[^>]*>default</\1>'))
```

Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
soup.find_all("template",{"v-slot:default-version" : True})
```